# VScode extension for changing Multiline `Postfix` for long commands (powershell to shell)?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Is there a **vscode extension** out to help me? I found nothing on the marketplace. May I search with the wrong key words :-)

If there is no extension available, may a js-snippet would help, then I can wrap it myself in a extension. Or any other ideas to solve the issue, to convert these two formats would help.

I wrote documentaion for docker commands, which become often very long, so I need to wrap the lines. The docu should cover shell and powershell syntax.

> My question is not limited to docker, but is a use case.

I am aware of `\` (slash) or shell and also `` ` `` (backtick) for poweshell. And also the different usages of pwd, like `$pwd` and `${PWD}`.

Here one example command, in bash

```bash
docker run \
  --interactive \
  --tty \
  --env PORT=8123 \
  --publish 8123:8123 \
  --name my-running-script \
  -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app \
  -w /usr/src/app \
  node:latest node server.js
```

Here same example command, in powershell

```
docker run `
  --interactive `
  --tty `
  --env PORT=8123 `
  --publish 8123:8123 `
  --name my-running-script `
  -v "${PWD}":/usr/src/app `
  -w /usr/src/app `
  node:latest node server.js
```

The extension / snippet should do the change from the line postfix (line wrpaper) from `\` to `` ` `` and also the change from `$PWD` to `${PWD}` and maybe also the other way round.

Comment: Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** on Stack Overflow for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic). Check if your question [is on-topic for softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), or [edit] it to be on-topic here on SO, or ask elsewhere outside Stack Exchange, or [do some research yourself](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11107541).

Comment: Thanks. I re-created the question there: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/85175/82627. Later I will also update / edit the text here on SO.

Comment: that is a very simple extension that does a few find/replace operations on the selection and puts the result back as a selection, just write it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You could just run two Find and Replaces pretty easily (disable the regex option) or some extensions allow you to run multiple find/replaces in a series.

Like [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), which I wrote.  Here is a simple keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`) to do this:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+right",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {

    "find": ["\\", "$PWD"],      // two finds, a \ must be escaped in JSON
    "replace": ["`", "${PWD}"],  // two replaces
    "isRegex": false,
            
    // "restrictFind": "selections"  // entire document or only within selections
  }
},
```

I think you can see how to make a reversal keybinding.